# Android recycle view in fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

**My Adapter**

```
public class DepartmentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DepartmentsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

// Store a member variable for the contacts
private List<AppDepartments> mDepartments;
// Store the context for easy access
private Context mContext;


@Override
public DepartmentsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // Inflate the custom layout
    View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_department_item, parent, false);
    // Return a new holder instance
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Involves populating data into the item through holder
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DepartmentsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    AppDepartments appDepartments = mDepartments.get(position);
    // Set item views based on your views and data model
   /* holder.txtViewName.setText(appDepartments.getDeptName());
    holder.txtViewUser.setText(appDepartments.getDeptUser());*/
    holder.txtViewName.setText("HELLO");
    holder.txtViewUser.setText("ITS VICTOR");

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

**My Fragment**

```
public class DiscoverFragment extends Fragment {

public DiscoverFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover, container, false);
    departmentsAdapter = new DepartmentsAdapter(getActivity(),departList);
    // Lookup the recyclerview in activity layout
    RecyclerView displayDeparts = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.appDepartments);
    displayDeparts.setAdapter(departmentsAdapter);
    displayDeparts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

}

The above code returns a blank screen,the textviews are not displayed. Kindly help.
I have commented out the model so that i can test with hard coded texts.
I was following this post http://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView

Comment: don't forget to fill `departList ` values

Comment: You have not added any value to departList and in getItemCount of Adapter return departList.size() instead of 0

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDepartments.size();
}
```

(not sure it will completely solve your problem)

Comment: most likely will make app crash, since `mDepartments ` at OP sample code is still null

Comment: Yes because it's not instantiated yet. Try to :
`private List<AppDepartments> mDepartments = new ArrayList<AppDepartments>();`

Comment: Instead of returning just size do this...
`return mDepartments== null ? 0 : mDepartments.size();`

Comment: @Sigma it solved the issue but now the same item is repeated 12 times

Comment: also you need to change getItemId

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `LayoutManager` to `RecyclerView` before setting adapter.

change code like this

```
displayDeparts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
displayDeparts.setAdapter(departmentsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your code `onViewCreated`  as below from my code :

```
   @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("AppPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit = pref.edit();

        swipe_container_reports = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container_reports);

        swipe_container_reports.setColorSchemeResources(
                R.color.colorAccent,
                R.color.colorPrimaryDark,
                R.color.cardview_dark_background);

        swipe_container_reports.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        //Recycler View
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.reports_recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        swipe_container_reports.setRefreshing(true);

        reportingUserTask = (ReportingUserTask) new ReportingUserTask(getContext(), Integer.valueOf(pref.getString("UserId", "")));
        reportingUserTask.setOnFinishListener(this);
        reportingUserTask.execute();

    }
```

also when the Task is finish in call Following :

```
adapter = new ReportRecyclerAdapter((ArrayList<ReportDetail>) reportDetailList, Integer.valueOf(pref.getString("UserId", "")), getContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This works flawlessly for me

Answer (score 0):

In your code:
 `setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()))` before `setAdapter(departmentsAdapter)`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover, container, false);
    displayDeparts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    departmentsAdapter = new DepartmentsAdapter(getActivity(), departList);
    // Lookup the recyclerview in activity layout
    RecyclerView displayDeparts = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.appDepartments);
    displayDeparts.setAdapter(departmentsAdapter);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDepartments.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set LayoutManager and then setAdapter to recyclerView like this:

```
RecyclerView displayDeparts = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.appDepartments);
departmentsAdapter = new DepartmentsAdapter(getActivity(),departList);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
displayDeparts.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
displayDeparts.setAdapter(departmentsAdapter);
```